# XmlSerializer, deserializing time only into DateTime type

Tags: datetime, xmlserializer

My WCF uses XmlSerializer to serialize and deserialize fairly complex objects.  Problem is, the corresponding XML payload value of one of the DateTime properties could be specified as either xs:date, xs:time or xs:dateTime values.  I've noticed that when a time-only value (e.g. 16:55:00Z) is specified in the input XML the current date gets 'prepended' during deserialization (e.g. 2010-12-13T16:55:00Z).  This obviously creates false data, I would rather have preferred DateTime.MinValue.
Is there a way I can control this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does this make sense? It makes as much sense as a property that could be int, string, or base64.

Comment: I agree yes, its another one of those cases where one has no control over the data that gets sent your way.  What makes just as little sense to me though is why the current date is simply added during deserialization

Answer (score 0):

We use WCFDate to send the date part as xs:date.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182960/WCF-Support-for-xs-date for code.